# How to get event target's parent with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery's event object to get the target's parent. The code is:

```
event.target.parentElement
```

In Chrome it works, but in Firefox, it doesn't. I use `alert()` to print the output.

`event.target` is an URL in both Chrome and Firefox; but `event.target.parentElement` in Chrome is [Element object], and in Firefox it is `null`.

What should I do to solve this problem? I still wonder if IE will have this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you paste the enclosing code for this?

Comment: i just use json ajax to get response from server , i will return a event object ,and then i use the event object.

Comment: you can use event.target.parent() function.

Comment: i originally use event.target.parent() function , but i doesn't work in both browser.

Comment: check this fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gx2ZF/

Answer (score 105, accepted):

To access the parent, you could do:

```
var par = $(event.target).parent();
```

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve an element from an inline link's target, it may be better to use the hash attribute of target, thusly:

```
(function($) {
    parent = $(event.target.hash).parent();
})(jQuery);
```

And btw, instead of alert, you can get much more information using `console.log` with either firefox/firebug or chrome.